# DebianInstaller not started

Tags: vagrant, packer

Here is my `build.json` file for packer

```
{
    "builders": [{
        "type": "virtualbox-iso",

        "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
        "http_directory": "http",
        "iso_url": "http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint//stable/18/linuxmint-18-xfce-64bit.iso",
        "iso_checksum_url": "https://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/linuxmint.com/stable/18/sha256sum.txt",
        "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
        "ssh_username": "vagrant",
        "ssh_password": "vagrant",
        "boot_command": [
            "<esc><wait><esc><wait>",
            "/casper/vmlinuz initrd=/casper/initrd.lz",
            " url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg",
            " boot=casper automatic-ubiquity quiet splash noprompt",
            " -- ",
            "<enter>"
        ],
        "shutdown_command": "echo 'vagrant' | sudo -S shutdown -P now",
        "hard_drive_interface": "sata",
        "output_directory": "target",
        "vboxmanage": [
            ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "2048"],
            ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "2"]
        ]
    }]
}
```

and my `preseed.cfg` (located in http sub dir)

```
#Step 1
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

#Step 2
d-i time/zone string Europe/Warsaw

#Step 3
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string pl

#Step 4
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true

#Step 5
d-i passwd/user-fullname string vagrant
d-i passwd/username string vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password password vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password-again password vagrant
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string vagrant
d-i passwd/auto-login boolean true

# Use non-free packages
ubiquity ubiquity/use_nonfree boolean true

#if you want to start commands after the installation
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target apt-get -y install openssh-server && /etc/init.d/ssh restart;

#Step 6
ubiquity ubiquity/summary note
ubiquity ubiquity/reboot boolean true
```

My understanding is that `"http_directory": "http"`, publish via http server and `url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg` should load it. However this isn't happening. Machine only boots into Linux Mint and I can manual install via GUI. What am I missing?

Comment: What's weird I changed from Mint 18 xfce to Mint 17.3 xfce  and it does installed. Is it some bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this problem whilst trying to preseed mint 18 kde, and discovered that pressing 'esc' to get the 'boot:' prompt always seemed to just boot to the live cd, no matter what I typed at that prompt.

However, hitting tab on the first menu item, removing the command, and replacing it with my own then boots into ubiquity. Here's my boot command from my packer file:

```
"boot_command": [
  "<esc><wait><tab><wait><leftCtrlOn>u<leftCtrlOff>",
  "/casper/vmlinuz initrd=/casper/initrd.lz",
  " url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg",
  " automatic-ubiquity debug-ubiquity boot=casper nosplash noprompt",
  " -- ",
  "<enter>"
]
```

This brings up the first boot command and uses ctrl-u to clear the line and type the command I want.